# Question about extending a property in a sub class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working through the *O Reilly Python Cookbook*.

I have a question about the following code, to do with extending a property in a sub class:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    # Getter function
    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    # Setter function
    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        if not isinstance(value, str):
            raise TypeError('Expected a string')
        self._name = value

    @name.deleter
    def name(self):
        raise AttributeError("Can't delete attribute")

class SubPerson(Person):
    @property
    def name(self):
        print('Getting name')
        return super().name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        print('Setting name to', value)
        super(SubPerson, SubPerson).name.__set__(self, value)

    @name.deleter
    def name(self):
        print('Deleting name')
        super(SubPerson, SubPerson).name.__delete__(self)
```

I'm confused about:

```
super(SubPerson, SubPerson).name.__set__(self, value)
```

With super(SubPerson,SubPerson) it seems to be accessing the method as a class variable, why cant it access the method as an instance variable instead?

Also, how does **set** and @name.setter relate to one another? Aren't they effectively the same thing?

Could the same line be written as:

```
super(SubPerson, SubPerson).name.settr(self,value)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two questions here.

First is about `super(SubPerson, SubPerson)`. It is just a trick to access the actual *property* object which is an attribute of the class. What is wanted here is `Person.name`, because once we have it, we can use the setter and deleter functions of the property. The problem with `super().name` or with any instance type access is that `super()` does not return an object but a proxy. And the property name on the proxy will only give access to the getter.

The latter is about `@name.setter`. In fact `property` as the initial decorator defines `name` as a property object. The `setter` attribute of a property is also a decorator that sets the setter function on its object and returns the object. That means that it is only intented to be used at class definition time. In fact the `@name.setter` bloc is roughly equivalent to the following code after the class definition:

```
def foo(self, value):
    ...
SubPerson.name = SubPerson.name.setter(foo)
```

The method that you wanted to use is the `fset` attribute of the property. That means that the setter part could have been written as :

```
@name.setter
def name(self, value):
    print('Setting name to', value)
    super(SubPerson, SubPerson).name.fset(self, value)
```